# Send messages to and receive messages from Azure Service Bus queues

Tags: r, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have to send & receive messages between `R` and `Azure Service Bus`. This is possible with [Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues), [Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues), [.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues) but there is no help for `R` script. As I'm limited to use only `R` to achieve this, is there any resource/documentation available to refer.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-guide/technology-choices/r-developers-guide?msclkid=9c4f27c4c4b811ecad0b5038b4f88f0e#azure-services-with-r-language-support), Currently, R programming doesn't support the Azure Service bus service. As of now Data Science Virtual Machine, ML Services on HDInsight, Azure Databricks, Azure Machine Learning, Azure Batch and Azure SQL Managed Instance are the only Azure services that are compatible with R programming.

Comment: That's a useful link. Do you think implementing my requirement on Java and call this Java from R script would be feasible? I need two way communication between R and Azure Service Bus

Comment: @msr_003, Haven't really tried but it may work